# Split a JsonArray

Tags: java, json

I'd like to split a `JsonArray` from the package `javax.json` and I can't find a convenient method that does the job. I looked through the documentation and I can only think of iterating over the `JsonArray` and adding the items manually using the `JsonArrayBuilder`.

Is there a more convenient way to split the array?

**Please note that I can't use another package (such as `google.gson`).**

Thanks in advance.

edit: I have a `JsonArray` of size `N` and I'd like to split it by indexes `from` and `to` and save the result as a `JsonArray`.

something like this:

```
JsonArray array1 = getJsonArrayOfSize(10);
JsonArray array2 = array1.split(2,5);
```

Comment: Convert your `JsonArray` to List and then split each items in `List`.

Comment: Show an example?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by split the array?

Comment: @VishwaRatna I added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) method:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ints = IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        JsonArrayExt array = new JsonArrayExt(ints);

        JsonArray array1 = array.subList(2, 5);
        System.out.println(array);
        System.out.println(array1);
    }
}

class JsonArrayExt {
    private final JsonArray array;

    public JsonArrayExt(List<Integer> ints) {
        this(Json.createArrayBuilder(ints).build());
    }

    public JsonArrayExt(JsonArray array) {
        this.array = Objects.requireNonNull(array);
    }

    public JsonArray subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        JsonArrayBuilder builder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        array.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).forEach(builder::add);

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return array.toString();
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

with Gson

```
List<MyModel> myModelList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);
```

**Updated**

you can create a utility for the same if you only want to use **javax.json** package. Below is the complete sample code with only **javax.json.*** package.

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.json.JsonValue;

```
public class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str =     "{\r\n" + 
                         "\"name\":\"John\",\r\n" + 
                         "\"age\":30,\r\n" + 
                         "\"cars\":[ \"Ford\", \"BMW\", \"Fiat\" ]\r\n" + 
                         "}";

        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(str));
        JsonObject object = reader.readObject();
        JsonArray array = object.getJsonArray("cars");
        System.out.println(getJsonArrayFromIndex(1, 2, array));
        System.out.println(getJsonArrayFromIndex(0, 2, array));
        System.out.println(getJsonArrayFromIndex(0, 1, array));
    }

    public static List<JsonValue> getJsonArrayFromIndex(int start, int end, JsonArray array) {
        return array.subList(start, end);       
    }
}
```

**output**

```
[BMW]
[Ford, BMW]
[Ford]
```

Comment: **Please note that I can't use another package (such as `google.gson`).** DId you read that?